# C++ - how is is_default_constructible implemented?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Could you explain me how can templates, such as is_default_constructible or is_move_constructible, look inside a class to check if a constructor is marked as "default" or it is a move constructor?

Comment: Note that `is_default_constructible` doesn't test if the constructor `= default` but if the constructor can be used with no parameters. It can still be user defined.

Answer (score 4):

`is_default_constructible<T>` does not discern a defaulted (`= default`) default constructor. It discerns *mostly* whether `T()` is a valid initialization (note: not `T{}`).

A first approximation is:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_default_constructible : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct is_default_constructible<T, std::void_t<decltype(T())>> : std::true_type { };
```

There's additional nuance in the standard version, because for example `void` is not default constructible but `void()` is a valid expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the validity of an expression at compile-time in multiple ways. The [detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) is a C++11 technique that could be used to implement the traits you mentioned. Here's an example *(this is an approximation, the actual `is_default_constructible` is more complicated)*:

```
template <class T>
using default_constructible_impl = decltype(T{});

template <class T>
using is_default_constructible = std::is_detected<default_constructible_impl, T>;
```

Here's an article I wrote on the subject that you might find useful: [**"checking expression validity in-place with C++17"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/checking_expression_validity_in_place.html). Despite what its title suggests, it also covers C++11 and C++14 techniques.

Comment: Note that not all such traits can work this way: std library can and does require traits that cannot be implemented in C++ without "cheating".  And some traits that can be implemented may be implemented by cheating anyhow (as a concrete example, integer sequence generation in msvc cheats).

Comment: Nope, that's not `is_default_constructible`. And there's no `std::is_detected_t`.